# Why subdomain is not working in Ubuntu nginx server?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, server

There a running Laravel application in the root folder of my ubuntu nginx server. Now i am trying to create a subdomain and run another Laravel application there. For instance,

1. findosman.xyz (root, running laravel app)
2. api.devport.findosman.xyz (another Laravel API)

Here is my current configuration;
In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.devport.findosman.xyz`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/api-devport;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name api.devport.findosman.xyz;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Here is the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.devport.findosman.xyz`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/api-devport;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name api.devport.findosman.xyz;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

In `/var/www/api-devport` I have currently only a `index.php` file which only has `<?php echo "hello world"?>`

the root folder project is running fine. but wherever I am trying to access `devport.findosman.xyz` it shows The site can't be reached.

How to overcome this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already set your DNS to point that subdomain to your server? "The site can't be reached" sounds like improper DNS settings for your domain.

Comment: I pointed DNS to the same ip of the root server